# How to run the service Using a kebernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I've a service running on my Kubernetes with the type loadBalancer.

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-services-dashboard
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 5005
      targetPort: 5005
  externalIPs: 
    - 1.2.4.120     
  selector:
    app: flask-app-dashboard
```

It has created the External-IP 127.0.0.1. But I need to provide my own External-IP for that I've given 1.2.4.120 as there on the above code.

It also generates the External-IP which I gave. but, I'm Unable to access it and showing **This site can’t be reached1.2.4.120 took too long to respond.**

How can I access the application using the External-IP which I've given?

Comment: generally we don't specify externalIPs in the svc def - the deployment process will assign the proper IP that you can find by `kubectl get service`.

what do you see if you query the service via kubectl?  it will either show an IP or "pending" if kubernetes (or minikube) is not configured for ingress.

Comment: It depends on which kubernetes platform do you use. If it is service like GKE, you can use existing IP to map to your LoadBalancer service.

Comment: What is running on that IP address?  How does it know to reach your cluster?